# MVC Route template parameters of different types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a MVC controller with a get method that takes 2 parameters, taxid and number.
The second parameter (number) can either be a string or an int.

I came up with the following signature, so that the second parameter accepts both alpha or int.

```html
  [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
       [Route("{taxId:int}/{number:alpha}")]
       [Route("{taxId:int}/{number:int}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetBy(String taxId, String number)
```

I was wondering if these 2 route parameter could be combined into one line, something like:

`[Route("{taxId:int}/{number:alpha||int}")]`

Comment: Have you tried: `[Route("{taxId:int}/{number:(alpha|int)}")]`?

Comment: @beautifulcoder Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it with no luck.

Comment: I don't see any documentation that says this is supported. You could download the source and check `RouteAttribute`. `DPack` can help you when spelunking through code

Comment: @beautifulcoder Yes I suspected it was not supported, as I could not find any example. Thanks.

Comment: More light on this is shed at this page http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2013/12/attribute-routing-with-aspnet-mvc-5.html We can add multiple constraints separated by a column.